# Deleting rows from Oracle table user_scheduler_job_run_details

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Oracle Database 12c
Red Hat Linux 7

I want to delete the last 1000 records on the Oracle table user_scheduler_job_run_details because it is getting too large.
How best to delete rows from the Oracle table user_scheduler_job_run_details? 
Are any precautions needed?
Is it simply a matter of doing a DELETE FROM ... DML statement?
Is there an existing job or procedure that handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it in days, not number of rows.

[DBMS_SCHEDULER.PURGE_LOG](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#i1011299)

> By default, the Scheduler automatically purges all rows in the job log
>   and window log that are older than 30 days. The PURGE_LOG procedure is
>   used to purge additional rows from the job and window log.
>
> log_history
>
> This specifies how much history (in days) to keep. The valid range is
>   0 - 1000000. If set to 0, no history is kept.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.PURGE_LOG (
   log_history             IN PLS_INTEGER  DEFAULT 0,
   which_log               IN VARCHAR2     DEFAULT 'JOB_AND_WINDOW_LOG',
   job_name                IN VARCHAR2     DEFAULT NULL);
```